# Why does CTRL + A Not Work in my sapui5 Application?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

Why does `CTRL + A` not work in my sapui5 application in a `INPUT` Field? `CTRL + V`and `CTRL + C` work. I have searched, but I didn't find anything on this topic. Perhaps my keywords were wrong.

Does someone know why it is not working?

Comment: What version of SAPUI5 are you using?

Comment: Have you tried sample applications in your browser with SAPUI5 just to make sure is not a browser issue? I'm currently trying this sample and CTRL + A, CTRL + C, CTRL + V all work ok.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputAssisted/preview

Comment: For me they work too, check https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933 here to see if you browser is supported

Comment: i tried its the same.. basicly it works on other views but in my view where i want it i dosnt work. My code:  <t:toolbar>
     <Toolbar> 
      <content> 
       <Title id="title" text="Übersichtsliste"/>
       <ToolbarSpacer/>
       <Input id="von" width="20%" placeholder="von" />
       <Input id="bis" width="20%" placeholder="bis" />
       <Button id="anwenden" text="Anwenden" press="anwendenDatumPress"/>
      </content>
     </Toolbar>
    </t:toolbar>and here it is not working in the input field control + a.. maybe it hase something to do, thats it is in the toolbar?